Can I drill and glue a barb fitting into ABS drain stack?
In California, USA, I have a boiler which is not connected to any portable water systems. I want to connect its condensate drain into a nearby 3" vertical ABS drain stack.
Fittings for this seem hard to find, and I'd rather not cut the vertical stack.
Can I drill a hole into the ABS and glue in a barb fitting?
The boiler manual allows me to loop the condensate drain as a trap.
Here is a YouTube video that shows something similar to what I'm thinking except I only need to tap for 3/8"
https://youtu.be/mo9zY5GMCG0?si=4Tc3kElcAbOt0_8G

Is there a clean out fitting near by on the stack?  I believe there are clean out caps for this use.

Condensing boiler is going to have a gas- and liquid-tight sealed exhaust system to the outdoors, but what about the combustion air inlet? Does the air come from the room, or is it piped in from outdoors too?

@greghill I'm not asking about inlet/exhaust. I'm only asking about the condensate drain.

Yes. I ask because one of the concerns that can arise with a condensate direct-connect is that sewer gases may vent backward through the condensate line. You mentioned a loop in the line as a trap, which may help address the concern, but I'm thinking about the whole system: what if the trap dries out or is removed, where do gases go? When the trap is wet, where's the vent path? Etc.

It is common to put these drains into sewer lines. The only novelty here is the aspect of drilling a hole to mount a barb fitting.

What's your hesitance about cutting the pipe?

@huesmann it's a vertical stack so I need to remove a larger section of wall, then replace solid pipe with two rubber clamp couplings and a gigantic Frankenstein fitting in between them. Drilling and gluing in a barb would require only a tiny hole and would not compromise any vertical pipe support
